# React useEffect trying to set Object at the same time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have different components that use `useEffect` on initialize to set the same variable which doesn't really work.

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
```

Im passing `setErrors` to the components which adds its own `localError` based on another parameter `type` and some functions to the (global)`error` object on initialize.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const newErrors: Object = {...errors};
    newErrors[type] = localError;
    setErrors(newErrors);
  }, []);
```

Now, if I have multiple of these components and they all have a `useEffect` they try to set the Object at (nearly) the same time which results in only the last rendered error being able to see in the error object.
I also realized that `setErrors` gets triggered even if its the same object as I am copying it. Is there a way to make this work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `errors`, but errors is not a dependency, the `useEffect` block would always contain the original `errors` (an empty object), and would just add the original `localError` and `type`, even if one of changes later.

Use the functional updates option of `useState()`, and make `localError` and the `type` a dependency of your `useEffect`. This will prevent changes in `errors` from causing the `useEffect` to activate, but due to the functional updates, you'll always get the updates `errors` as `prevErrors`. In addition, changes to `localError` or `type` would cause the loop to be called, and add the new error.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setErrors(prevErrors = ({
    ...prevErrors,
    [type]: localError
  }));
}, [localError, type]);
```

I don't have the rest of your code, but you probably want to avoid setting the error if `localError` or `type` are `undefined` or `null`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!type || !localError) return;

  setErrors(prevErrors = ({
    ...prevErrors,
    [type]: localError
  }));
}, [localError, type]);
```